# cannot setState in React app

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create an element in React that would fade in after loading page.
From debugging I understand that setState is not working as I would like it to work.

```
const divHeight = 100;
const divWidth = 300;

class ProbaShell extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      h: divHeight,
      w: divWidth
    };

    this.fadeIn = this.fadeIn.bind(this);
  }

  fadeIn(){
    // alert('fadeInFunc');
    var divH = document.getElementById('kwadrat').clientHeight;

    while(divH <= 400){
      divH = divH + 5;
      this.setState({ h: divH });
      var sh = this.state.h;
    };
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <Proba style = {{height: this.state.h}}/>
    )
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    alert('fadeInCall');
    this.fadeIn();
  }
}
```

and  second part:

```
import React from 'react';

class Proba extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div ref = 'kwadrat' id = 'kwadrat'>
        {alert('kwadrat')}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

why I cannot update the state and change the size of the div?

Comment: What does this say: `this.setState({ h: divH }, () => console.log(this.state.h));` Or how did you debug your workflow and determine that `setState` doesn't work?

Comment: You shouldn't use alert like this, because it blocks the flow, and it may be the reason why your code doesn't work. Use console.log instead if you need to track what is happening.

Comment: Is the loop resulting anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three problems in your code :

1. The `while` loop is too fast for you to see any motion. To fix this, I proposed a `setInterval` solution below.
2. You are giving `style` to the `<Proba>` component thinking it's the default HTML attribute. It's in fact nothing but a prop, the solution below fixes that as well.
3. You are placing spaces around the `=` signs in the defintion of your props and that is not recommended.

Here is the render method of the `Proba` component :

```
function render() {
    return (
        // set the style as a normal prop, it will work here because this
        // is a simple <div>, not a component
        <div ref="kwadrat" id="kwadrat" style={ this.props.style }>
            kwadrat
        </div>
    );
}
```

Here is the `fadeIn` method :

```
fadeIn() {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.setState({ h: (this.state.h + 5) });
        if (this.state.h >= 400) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        } 
    }, 50);
}
```

I have added a [codepen](https://codepen.io/glouhaichi/pen/WZOOwo) that shows a working example, in which I have added two different configurations for the movement of the `<div>` (`step` and `time`).

Answer (score 0):

First I want you to give you tipps to optimize your code:

Use arrow functions instead of bind():

```
this.fadeIn = () => this.fadeIn();
```

In this case it would be enough to just call the method like:

```
this.fadeIn();
```

Can you give me more informations about what do you want to do and how the components are structured (parent/child). I would never use document.getElementById in a React App...